# Is there anything like proxy but for cell phone?

Tags: privacy, cellular, cellular-internet

I want to know if there is something like a proxy, but for cellphone calls, not for smartphones, but controlling it from computer??

Comment: Your question is not very clear.

From what I am reading, it seems that you want to make a phone call from your computer?

Comment: @francisswest I want to have anonymity my cellphone through something like a proxy, and my computer register the information...

Comment: Just curious...Why?

Comment: @francisswest I'm from Mexico, as you know, insecurity is a real issue here, so I'd like to know if it's possible in order to have anonymity when I call

Comment: Any time you connect to a network, that can be seen. Even if you're on a VPN, with encrypted traffic, it can be seen what you're connecting to, even if the traffic itself is secure. Skype behind Tor is probably a reasonable idea, but your ISP will see that you're connecting to Tor.

Comment: But if I'm behind a proxy, they final receiver just see the proxy, not my, unless they intercept the communication between me and proxy?? @RandolphWest

Comment: Theoretically, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just use an app like Skype and use a VPN or set a proxy?

You can run the call on your WiFi and use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to trace the info of the call. Or set your computer as the cellphone's access point and use a proxy for your PC. To hide yourself online even more, change your [UserAgent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserAgent) ID.

I typed this and saw the "no smartphone" part, so ignore if this offers no help. It won't be possible on a normal cell.

Comment: well, I saw something like type "*67" before the number, and it apparently works, but here in my country, I cannot make these kind of phone calls, skype could be a good option

Comment: Yes just remember that skype will also only be safe encrypted and using a proxy maybe... And the people you are hiding from cant be on your network else it is VERY easy to catch the packets and listen in on the conversation.

Comment: Why do you think Skype is secure? It is proprietary, owned by a corporation.

Comment: It is not that skype is so secure , but it rather sounds like he is trying to not be detected by another person or within mexico. I really doubt microsoft is listening in on every skype conversation if you meant that.

Comment: @Rudi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRISM_(surveillance_program) You can find the 4° slide interesting: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Prism_slide_5.jpg